# Query to update showing 0 records updated mongo

Tags: mongodb

Am using below query in `db.getcolletion`

```js
db.getCollection('publickdata').find({"mediatorProf" : "ctvdl Without audieo",
    "ProfileName":"p2_max_dls",ProfileDetails: 
    { $elemMatch: { Name: "psMaxdetail", Value: "Mozilla 13" } }})
```

I need to  update Value: `Mozilla 13` to Value: `Mozilla 12`

Am using below query:

```js
db.collection.update(   // or updateMany directly, removing the flag for 'multi'
   {"elemMatch.Value":"Mozilla 13"},
   {$set:{"elemMatch.$[].Value":"Mozilla 12"}},  // notice the empty brackets after '$' opearor
   false,
   true
)
```

output showing: Updated 0 records provide suggestions.

document is:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e31a24faa0f99e"),
    "lastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2020-02-29T16:18:39.664Z"),
    "mediatorProf" : "ctvdl Without audieo",
    "ProfileName" : "p2_max_dls",
    "ProfileDetails" : [ 

        {
            "Name" : "psMaxdetail",
            "Value" : "Mozilla 13"
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "iptvSupported",
            "Value" : "N"
        }  
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample `document`

Comment: db.getCollection('publickdata').find({"mediatorProf" : "ctvdl Without audieo", "ProfileName":"p2_max_dls",ProfileDetails: { $elemMatch: { Name: "psMaxdetail", Value: "Mozilla 13" } }})

Comment: need to updated Value from "Mozilla 13" to value : "Mozilla 12"

Comment: /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e31a24faa0f99e"),
    "lastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2020-02-29T16:18:39.664Z"),
    "mediatorProf" : "ctvdl Without audieo",
    "ProfileName" : "p2_max_dls",
    "ProfileDetails" : [ 
      
        {
            "Name" : "psMaxdetail",
            "Value" : "Mozilla 13"
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "iptvSupported",
            "Value" : "N"
        } 
      
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) along with arrayFilters.

```
db.publickdata.updateMany(
{
    "mediatorProf": "ctvdl Without audieo",
    "ProfileName": "p2_max_dls"
},
{
    $set:{
        "ProfileDetails.$[elem].Value": "Mozilla 12"
    },
    $unset:{
        "ProfileDetails.$[elem].AttributeValue": 1
    }
},
{
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [{"elem.Name": "psMaxdetail", "elem.Value": "Mozilla 13"}]
   }
);
```

Comment: "Name" : "psMaxdetail",
            "Value" : "Mozilla 12",
            "attributeValue" : "Mozilla 9"      in output value column is updated .....need to delete attributeValue column how can be acheivable.

Comment: "Name" : "psMaxdetail", "Value" : "Mozilla 12", "attributeValue" : "Mozilla 9"

Comment: above is the output we need to delete the column attributeValue column

Comment: You want to simultaneously delete another attribute? Edited my answer.